# I designed neg. edge-triggered jk flip-flop circuit in LTspice XVII. But, it doesn't work

Tags: ltspice, flipflop

Voltage sources work but, 74HC107(neg. edge-triggered jk flip-flop) doesn't work.

Output Q(0), Q(1), Q(2) turn out always 0V.

I can't understand what is the problem.....

Please help me......

And, actually my English skill is a little bad, so please bear with me.

[image]

This is the 74HC107 circuit that I made.

Q(0), Q(1), Q(2) are outputs.

V1 is a DC source, and this has constant 5V.

[image]

The picture on the bottom is V2 and CLK. (Period: 20μs, on time: 10μs)

[image]

And, setting of V2.

[image]

Graph of Q(0). As you can see, Q(0) turns out always 0V during simulation.

[image]

Graph of Q(1). Likewise, Q(1) turns out always 0V during simulation.

[image]

Graph of Q(2). Q(2) ditto....

[image]

Please... Help me....

Comment: The CLR inputs of your flip-flops are **unconnected**. NEVER leave inputs unconnected! always connect inputs propely. Also I do not see any **supply connections** (VSS, VDD) of that 74HC107 so do the flip-flops get a supply voltage? I also **stronly** advice you to take a step back and start with something **much simpler**, for example **only** that 74HC08 AND gate on its own. First get that to work, when it works add **one** flip-flop, get that to work etc...

Comment: Try connecting the `CLR` pins to Vdd. If the model has an internal grounding (pull-down) then it will count as a `true`. I don't know if it actually has internal pull down because the later versions of LTspice add a `Gmin` behind the scene to unconnected pins, but that causes confusion, IMHO, because the simulation will run but it might have wrong results. Best never let floating pins (unless special rules apply).

Comment: Not solving your main problem, but put a non-zero value in for your PULSE() rise and fall times.  Something like `100n`.  It will make your pulses closer to 50% duty, which looks like what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I just started using LTspice, so I don't know much about it. However, thanks to everyone, I'm able to solve these problems. I wanna reiterate how grateful I am.